# How is a negative number parsed in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Say `-1`, is `-` parsed as part of the literal as a sign, or an operator to turn the value into its negative counterpart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is parsed as part of the literal, and makes the literal a negate literal.

[Here's the reference](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/64fea27496bd10a5ccdb78abcd541f9c1a9174c8/parse.y#L4440-L4450) in the parser source code. If you search the file for `tUMINUS_NUM` and `tUMINUS` you'll see where the `-` token is defined.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Simone Carletti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38220361/477037):

```
$ ruby --dump=parsetree -e "-1"
###########################################################
## Do NOT use this node dump for any purpose other than  ##
## debug and research.  Compatibility is not guaranteed. ##
###########################################################

# @ NODE_SCOPE (line: 1)
# +- nd_tbl: (empty)
# +- nd_args:
# |   (null node)
# +- nd_body:
#     @ NODE_LIT (line: 1)
#     +- nd_lit: -1
```

As opposed to `-(1)`, `-+1` or `- 1` (with a space in between) which invoke [`Fixnum#-@`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-2D-40):

```
$ ruby --dump=parsetree -e "-(1)"
###########################################################
## Do NOT use this node dump for any purpose other than  ##
## debug and research.  Compatibility is not guaranteed. ##
###########################################################

# @ NODE_SCOPE (line: 1)
# +- nd_tbl: (empty)
# +- nd_args:
# |   (null node)
# +- nd_body:
#     @ NODE_CALL (line: 1)
#     +- nd_mid: :-@
#     +- nd_recv:
#     |   @ NODE_LIT (line: 1)
#     |   +- nd_lit: 1
#     +- nd_args:
#         (null node)
```